# How can use 'regexp_replace()' to replace from start position to end position in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have given `'THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO'`

I want to mask 1st 3rd 4th character with x in Postgres

Comment: 1st, 3rd, 4th of what? Each line? Each word? Please show what you have, i.e. make a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

If you want the replacement to occur for all four comma separated parts, you can use something like this:

```
WITH mytable(mystring) AS (SELECT 'THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO'::text)
SELECT string_agg(
          overlay(
             overlay(
                a.p
                placing 'x' from 1 for 1
             )
             placing 'xx' from 3 for 2
          ),
          ','
       )
FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL
      unnest(string_to_array(mystring, ',')) a(p);
```

That results in

```
┌────────────────────────────┐
│         string_agg         │
├────────────────────────────┤
│ xHxxAS,xAxxAN,xDxxJDJ,xOxx │
└────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

If you don't need the replacement to occur for all parts, but for the whole string, just use the two `overlay`s and forget the rest.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regex. One regex to obtain the places of insertion (where x should be) and another one to obtain the rest of substrings (where the text should remain intact).

The following should work also for shorter strings.

`SELECT test.replace_string_134('THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO,b,bl,bla');`

yield: `xHxxAS,xAxxAN,xDxxJDJ,xOxx,x,xl,xlx`

I post this as an alternate sample but for performance wise you can follow @LaurenzAlbe answer.

```
CREATE SCHEMA test;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test.replace_string_134 (TEXT)
 RETURNS TEXT
AS
$$
DECLARE
  input_text ALIAS FOR $1;
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT STRING_AGG(
      CASE WHEN tgroup.txt_group[1] <> '' THEN 'x' ELSE '' END
       || trest.txt_rest[1]
       || CASE WHEN tgroup.txt_group[2] <> '' THEN 'x' ELSE '' END
       || CASE WHEN tgroup.txt_group[3] <> '' THEN 'x' ELSE '' END
       || trest.txt_rest[2],
       ',')
      FROM
      (
        SELECT txt_group, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS txt_index
        FROM regexp_matches(input_text, '[,]?([^,])[^,]?([^,]?)([^,]?)[^,]*[,]?', 'g') AS txt_group
      ) AS tgroup
      INNER JOIN
      (
        SELECT txt_rest, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS txt_index
          FROM regexp_matches(input_text, '[,]?[^,]([^,]?)[^,]?[^,]?([^,]*)[,]?', 'g') AS txt_rest
      ) AS trest
        ON trest.txt_index = tgroup.txt_index
  );
END
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT test.replace_string_134('THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO,b,bl,bla');

DROP SCHEMA test CASCADE;
```

Comment: How to write a mask function in PostgreSQL which will take a given string and replace the given positions.

I pass ('THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO','1,2,3') it should result 'TxxxAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO'

Here '1,2,3' are the positions I want to replace with x

Comment: @JyotiranjanNayak I would recommend to you creating a new question containing your last comment as a question. Current question has already two answers which assumed that you needed the criteria to be applied to each substring separated by comma, which seems that was not what you desired. So better to open a new one that will be clearer and receive more targeted answers. And leave this one to solve replacing of characters on substrings delimited by comma.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606364/how-to-write-function-in-postgres-which-take-these-args-thomas-ranjan-jdjdjdj-o