# how to write function in postgres which take these args (THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO','1,2,3') and give 'TxxxAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO' as result

Tags: postgresql

How to write a mask function in PostgreSQL  which will take a given string and replace the given positions.

I pass `('THOMAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO','1,2,3')` it should result `'TxxxAS,RANJAN,JDJDJDJ,OOOO'`

Here '1,2,3' are the positions I want to replace with x

Comment: please read and edit your question

Comment: you should change it into something like "string replace where criteria is an array of indexes".

Comment: What was your best attempt at solving this problem?